Magento 2 : Change Billing Address drop-down to radio button on checkout page
I want to change the billing address drop down to radio button on checkout page.
Please help me, I tried but its not working.
I am not good in ko js as well.

share what you have try and which issue facing into that one?

Create extension for your requirement.

@DhirenVasoya Actually my requirements are changed but I will work on this later and post my solution here .  .Thank you

got any solution?
